# How do I import shaka-player into an angular 2 application

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2(latest) with typescript(latest) application working. I created a Component for video and everything is working okay. Now I would like to add shaka-player but, I got this:
TS2307:Cannot find module 'shaka-player'.

I installed the shaka-player and, it's listed into the node_modules folder.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import * as shaka from 'shaka-player';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to use shaka player in angular 2 (or greater) is by importing it as an external library in the angular-cli.json

1) Install shaka-player

```
npm install shaka-player --save
```

2) After First step open .angular.cli.json (v5) || angular.json (v6)

and add this snippet in scripts.

../node_modules/shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.compiled.js

3) Add Video element to your template

```
    <video id="video"
           width="640"
           poster="//shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/assets/poster.jpg"
           controls autoplay></video>
```

4) In your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var shaka: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shaka-player',
  templateUrl: './shaka-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shaka-player.component.scss']
})
export class ShakaPlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  manifestUri = '//storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one/dash.mpd';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initApp();
  }

  initApp() {
    // Install built-in polyfills to patch browser incompatibilities.
    shaka.polyfill.installAll();

    // Check to see if the browser supports the basic APIs Shaka needs.
    if (shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()) {
      // Everything looks good!
      this.initPlayer();
    } else {
      // This browser does not have the minimum set of APIs we need.
      console.error('Browser not supported!');
    }
  }

  initPlayer() {
  // Create a Player instance.
  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  const player = new shaka.Player(video);

    // Attach player to the window to make it easy to access in the JS console.
//window.player = player;

// Listen for error events.
player.addEventListener('error', this.onErrorEvent);

// Try to load a manifest.
// This is an asynchronous process.
player.load(this.manifestUri).then(function () {
  // This runs if the asynchronous load is successful.
  console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
}).catch(error => {this.onError(error)});  // onError is executed if the asynchronous load fails.
}

onErrorEvent(event) {
  // Extract the shaka.util.Error object from the event.
  this.onError(event.detail);
}

onError(error) {
  // Log the error.
  console.error('Error code', error.code, 'object', error);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to use shaka-player in an Angular 2 app.

**Compiling the library**

(See documentation here: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-welcome.html)

Go to `node_modules/shaka-player/build/`
Run the `build.py` script.

Then in the `node_modules/shaka-player/dist/` there are different files, I've picked `shaka-player.compiled.js` for simplicity.

---

**Using the library**

Inside my component's class I require the files and assign it to a variable:

`shaka = require('../../../../node_modules/shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.compiled');`

Then I can use this property of the class with the `this` notation:
`this.shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()`

You can then follow the official documentation not forgetting to use `this.shaka` instead of just `shaka`: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-basic-usage.html

---

**Modular approach**

For the library to be reused over the app it is possible to export`shaka` variable mentioned above from a separate `.ts` file.

`export var shaka = require('../../../../node_modules/shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.compiled');`

Then in the component file an ES6 import statement can be used:

`import {shaka} from '../../common/js-libs/shaka-player'`

From here the library can be used exactly like in the documentation, no need to use the `this` notation.

Creating a property of the class that copies `shaka` from the import statement is totally up to you.

Answer (score -1):

you should add  ad the following code in the component

```
import * as shaka from 'shaka-player';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detailpage',
  templateUrl: '<video #video id="video"
                    controls autoplay></video>  ',
  styleUrls: ['./detailpage.component.css'],
 })
export class DetailpageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('video') videoElement: ElementRef;
   ngOnInit() {
shaka.polyfill.installAll();
if (shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()) {
  const video = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
  const player = new shaka.Player(video);
  const manifestUri = 'your rul';

  player.addEventListener('error', ErrorEvent);
  player.load(manifestUri).then(function() {
    console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
  }).catch(onerror);  
 } else {
  console.error('Browser not supported!');
 }
}
```